# How to make selection from AppleScript dialog list with keystroke?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, shortcut

I've created an application with AppleScript in Automator.

The application, right off the bat, presents the user with a dialog list.

By default, there are two ways to select an item from the list:

1. Using your mouse.
2. Using the arrow keys on your keyboard.

However, what I would like to do is offer the user a third option: to select the item based on a keystroke or keyboard shortcut. I would also like the selected item to be submitted directly after the keystroke or keyboard shortcut is pressed.

For example:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set FruitList to {"Banana (#1)", "Kiwi (#2)", "Mango (#3)", "Coconut (#4)", "Pear (#5)"}

    set FavoriteFruitAnswer to choose from list FruitList with title "Fruit Dialog" with prompt "What's your favorite fruit?" default items "Banana (#1)"


    if FavoriteFruitAnswer is false then
        error number -128 (* user cancelled *)
    else
        set FavoriteFruitAnswer to FavoriteFruitAnswer's item 1 (* extract choice from list *)
    end if

    return input
end run
```

The preceding code produces the following:

[image]

What I want to occur is if the user presses the number "2" on their keyboard, therefore "Kiwi (#2)" is selected and then the "OK" button is automatically pressed. If the user presses the number "4" on their keyboard, therefore "Coconut (#4)" is selected and then the "OK" button is automatically pressed. And so on.

Is this possible?

What I know is possible is to create a dialog box with a text field where the user types in the number manually and then the user hits enter manually and the number is assigned to the corresponding fruit type.

But that's not a particularly pretty solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppleScript is not robust enough to do exactly what you're asking, however if you want to be able to select by *number* then put the *number* ahead of the *name of the fruit*, although <kbd>enter</kbd> will still need to be pressed after the *number* is pressed. Otherwise, pressing whatever the first character of the *list item* entry is will select it too.

For example, change the following two lines of code from:

```
set FruitList to {"Banana (#1)", "Kiwi (#2)", "Mango (#3)", "Coconut (#4)", "Pear (#5)"}
set FavoriteFruitAnswer to choose from list FruitList with title "Fruit Dialog" with prompt "What's your favorite fruit?" default items "Banana (#1)"
```

To:

```
set FruitList to {"1. Banana", "2. Kiwi", "3. Mango", "4. Coconut", "5. Pear"}
set FavoriteFruitAnswer to choose from list FruitList with title "Fruit Dialog" with prompt "What's your favorite fruit?" default items "1. Banana"
```

---

As a side note, double-clicking a list entry to select it with the mouse does also trigger the <kbd>enter</kbd> key press automatically.